# Is there a difference between token price fixed on smart contract and token price on market?

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, ico

i set an initial price for my token in solidity, how does It Works the price on the market? if i set a fixed variable TokenPrice in my smart contract, can my token price change thanks to request_offer of market?
The price that i fixed in the smart contract and the price of the market are differents?

Comment: I really can't get your point! Please provide some code of your contract or describe your point more! If you are setting a fixed variable, it won't change if market price changes!

Comment: I would like to fixed an ICO for my token(example 200 dollars), but on etherscan there is 0 dollars.             What can i write in solidity the initial price of my token ?

Comment: Oh, you want to make an ICO contract! Price on etherscan is not related to the price you set in your contract. Etherscan show price related to the market, not your ICO contract

Comment: You want the code of ICO and how to set price?!

Comment: Yes but  i have yet an ICO contract(where i set totalsupply) but i wanted to set an initial price to my token. But i saw in a YouTube video that the price on etherscan comes from coinmarketcap. Now i can set an initial price on my token ? If yes, where Will initial price appear on etherscan?

Comment: Yes, you can but it won't appear on etherscan, it will be shown in the site you do the ICO. If your token becomes famous and be listed on Coinmarketcap, its price will be shown in etherscan

Comment: so if I throw my token, on etherscan it will have a value of zero because it is not listed yet. If I want to give an initial sales value, I have to make it visible through a website or any other platform to make it available to possible lenders, right?

Comment: Absolutely right!

Comment: you are very kind! one last question: so I don't need to set a fixed variable in my code which represents the starting price. I can simply write the initial price of the token or on the "update informations" item on etherscan (where I can modify the project description, insert the logo, insert website links) or for example make a website where I present my project and I describe the initial offer

Comment: Thank you. In your solidity you must declare and define the price, and in the website you make or want to do the ICO (not etherscan) you show the price

Comment: what do i need to insert a fixed variable in the code? is it only needed if someone wants to verify that the price shown on my website is the same as the price set in the smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I show you a small example of solidity and JS code of ICO and how you can do it

solidity:

```
contract OwnerContract{
  address owner;
  constructor(){
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
  modifier isOwner(){
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Access denied!");
    _;
  }
}

//Interface of standard token if you want to accept for example USDT token (as in this example)
interface IERC20{
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract ICO_Contract is ownerContract{
  //Declare the price and ICO token sell amount
  uint256 eachTokenPrice;
  uint256 maximumAmount;
  uint256 sellAmount;

  constructor(uint256 maximumAmount_){
    maximumAmount = maximumAmount_;
  }

  modifier maximumReached(uint256 _amount){
    require((sellAmount + _amount) <= maximumAmount, "Maximum amount of ICO reached!");
    _;
  }
  //declare the USDT token
  address USDTtokenAddress = USDT_TOKEN_ADDRESS_ON_DEPLOYED_NETWORK;

  function changeUSDTtokenAddress(address _address) public isOwner{
    USDTtokenAddress = _address;
  }
  address ICOtokenAddress = TOKEN_ADDRESS_ICO;

  function changeICOtokenAddress(address _address) public isOwner{
    ICOtokenAddress = _address;
  }

  IERC20 USDTtoken = IERC20(USDTtokenAddress);
  IERC20 ICOtoken = IERC20(ICOtokenAddress);

  function buyToken(uint256 _amount) public maximumReached(_amount){
    require(_amount > 0, "You need to spend USDT");
    uint256 approvedAmount = USDTtoken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    require(approvedAmount == _amount, "Check the token allowance, not enough approved!");
    uint256 totalPrice = price * _amount * (USDtoken.decimals()/ICOtoken.decimals());
    USDTtoken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), totalPrice);
    //ICOtoken is in the contract
    ICOtoken.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    sellAmount += _amount;
  }
  
  function showPrice() external view returns(uint256){
    return price;
  }

  function showsoldAmount() external view returns(uint256){
    return sellAmount;
  }

  function showMaxAmount() external view returns(uint256){
    return maximumAmount;
  }
}
```

I guess this is it. (I did not test and it definitely will throw errors which you have to handle it)

JS code (ethers.js & ethereum libraries) (Because I don't know back-end language I only deploy front-end and just use front-end):

```
const {ethers} = require('ethers');

let price;
let soldAmount;
let maxAmount;
let provider;
let signer;
let signerAddress;
let contract;

const contractAddress = ICO_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
const contractABI = {'function showsoldAmount() external view returns(uint256)',
  'function showPrice() external view returns(uint256)',
  'function buyToken(uint256 _amount) external maximumReached(_amount)',
  'function showMaxAmount() external view returns(uint256)'}
  //Actually I am not sure if it needs modifier in the interface or not

async () => {
  await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  signer = provider.getSigner();
  signerAddress = await signer.getAddress();
  contract = await new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);
  price = await contract.showPrice();
  soldAmount= await contract.showSoldAmount();
  maxAmount = contract.showMaxAmount();
  //Show price and sold amount and maximum amount of selling in your page somewhere you want
}

//set a button and input in the page to call the buyToken function and connect it to function below.
function buyToken(){
  let amount = document.getElementById("INPUT_TO_KNOW_AMOUNT_ID").value;
  contract.buyToken(ethers.utils.parseEther(amount));
}
```

I hope I did not forget anything but if you have any question simply ask

Best regards :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have already a code for my smart contract. I have created an ERC20 TOKEN with name, Total supply, decimals... So now  i have to createa a front end that interact with smart contract allowing to buy my token (thansk to function buy on smart contract) right?

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make it clear. Yes you need to deploy front-end.